# oracle apex creates a session for 'nobody' user after logout

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

In my oracle apex application, I have written the code to delete application session after logging out from application. I delete the session from table wwv_flow_sessions$ as

```
delete from APEX_050000.wwv_flow_sessions$ where id=v('APP_SESSION');
```

where 'APP_SESSION' holds the logged session id. After the session is deleted, a new session creates with username 'nobody' in table wwv_flow_sessions$. When I login to the application next time, this session is assigned to newly logged user.My question is why does a session creates when I log out from the application

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT manually delete something in the internal tables of APEX. If your application does have a Logout link (use &LOGOUT_URL.) and the user clicks it, APEX will automatically do the necessary cleanup of your session. Based on your setting in Shared Components -> Authentication Schemes -> Current -> Post-Logout URL, APEX will decide what to do next. If your application specifies to go to the "Home Page", the APEX engine will have to create a new anonymous session until the user logs in. Keep in mind that even an unauthenticated user can have session state, ...

Comment: Short answer - it needs a session to render any page, including the login page. This behaviour is the same as initially visiting the login page.

Comment: @Patrick  and Scott, so you are saying that  an entry with username nobody will be created after a user logout from the application. And if 100thousand users logout from the application it will create 100thousand new sessions. Isn't?

Comment: Yes a session will be created if your Post-Logout URL points to the Home Page/Login Page of your application. If you want to avoid this behavior you can specify a custom URL in Authentication Scheme -> Post-Logout URL -> Go To=URL which points to a static HTML letting the user know that he is logged out.